# If I seek God, does that mean that I MUST be elect, according to Calvinism?

Tags: nature-of-god, reformed-theology, predestination, free-will, calvin

I want to find God, at least I think I do.  I struggle with the different interpretations of the path to salvation and even though I don't LIKE the idea of God electing some and giving others absolutely no chance for salvation ever, it does have some decent biblical support.  Maybe it is an inconvenient or hard to face truth, I'm not going to pretend I know the answer for sure.

I have heard the argument that it is literally not possible for a non elect to seek God.  They simply can't, they never will, they just inherently want nothing to do with him and people who do seek God, put what little faith they as a human being can muster into Jesus and pray to be saved then that is 100% proof that the individual was one of the chosen to be saved and they were willed by God to come to him and could not have rejected him no matter what.  Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: John Piper [says](http://www.desiringgod.org/articles/what-we-believe-about-the-five-points-of-calvinism), "It is a myth that man in his natural state is genuinely seeking God. Men do seek God. But they do not seek him for who he is." I was going to put that in an answer until I found the other question.